# in c++ why we declare reference parameter as const in overloaded function?

Tags: c++, function, reference, constants, overloading

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, 
                           const Distance &D)
{ 
    output << "F : " << D.feet << " I : " << D.inches;
    return output;            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't want the function that writes a instance to a stream to modify the instance.

And because a const reference, unlike a non-const one (unless you're using MSVC) can accept a temporary object, which is useful.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Safety**: with `const` we make sure we won't accidentaly modify the object.
2. **Speed**: References are much faster than passing by value. Also `const` tells the compiler the object won't be modified, therefore some optimizations could be made.

Comment: oh... Thank you. got it and i was having one more question that why we return 'by reference' in overloaded function?

Comment: I guess you are confused. Read legends2k's answer. You _are not_ obligated to use const/non-const references.

Comment: I read his comment. and i cleared with const concept. actually ma'am has asked the question which is confusing me... she has asked

Comment: Explain insertion(>>) and extraction(<<) operator overloading with an example also explain why we return by reference in overloaded function and why we declare reference parameter as const in overloaded function ?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO: passing by reference is more efficient than passing via copy and the const keyword stops you from altering the original instance...

Comment: @black: sorry you were faster

Answer (score 1):

> in c++ why we declare reference parameter as const in overloaded
>   function?

No, in the function that you've posted it's done so for the reasons mentioned in the other answers, but there's no requirement i.e. **the standard doesn't mandate that an overloaded function taking a reference parameter should be `const`**.

You're mixing up multiple things here. Overloading is a language feature where multiple functions with identical names can coexist, while `const` is a qualifier which says the data wouldn't change in a given context through that variable/function. They've no relationship that ties them saying it has to be a `const` if the overloading function takes a reference paramater. The same goes for reference variables too; they're just an alias (a different name) of another variable which has nothing to do with `const` or function overloading.

Answer (score 1):

It is not obligatory to define a reference parameter as const in overloaded functions. Simply in your example of the operator << the right operand is not changed in the function. This allows to use this operator with const objects.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

class Distance
{
public:
   //...
   friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, 
                              const Distance &D)
   { 
       output << "F : " << D.feet << " I : " << D.inches;
       return output;            
   }
private:
   float feet;
   //...
};

int main()
{
   const Distance d1;

   std::cout << d1 << std:;endl;
}
```

The compiler would issue an error parsing statement

```
   std::cout << d1 << std::endl;
```

if the second parameter in the operator << would be declared as a non-const reference.

Another example

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
   A() {}
   A( A & ) { std::cout << "A( A & )" << std::endl; }
   A( const A & ) { std::cout << "A( const A & )" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
   A a1;
   A a2( a1 );
   const A a3;
   A a4( a3 );
}
```

In this example there are two copy constructors one of which defines the parameter as non-const reference and the other defines the parameter as const reference.

If there would not be the second copy constructor then the compiler would issue an error parsing statement

```
   A a4( a3 );
```

Comment: Okkkk... Got it got it got it... :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

a function signature is a contract between the calling code and the function code.

You want that the function will require as less demands as possible.
If you write demanding signature like 
    ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Distance &D)

then you won't be able to call your operator from code that operates on const objects:

```
void Foo(const Distance& d) {
  cout << d;  // syntax error
}
```

in other words putting as less requirements as possible on function arguments makes your function more general.